# Java project: should .classpath .project file be committed into repository?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, classpath, versioning

Should I check in my .project and .classpath files?

My friend told me that I should only check in .java files and the build.xml to guarantee portability. He said ".classpath will cause you much less portability on different environment. .project is entirely your local eclipse setting"

I agree with him, but partially.

-- Not checking in .project file will make my development less efficient (I can't simply "import" a project code from a directory)

-- Not checking in .classpath file seems OK to me (?) if my build.xml is written carefully.

Anyone wants to share their experience here?

Comment: Note that if you use Maven and the m2eclipse plugin you will probably not need any of the settings from `.project` or `.classpath`. "import maven project" and "checkout maven project" will work fine with the `pom.xml` only.

Answer (score 31):

There is nothing wrong with checking in `.project` and `.classpath`. I would do so, if your `build.xml` isn't able to create both of the files for you. As you said, it's uncomfortable to miss these files when you try to create a new eclipse workspace.

Before you check in `.classpath` you should be sure that there is no absolute path in it. Convert it into a relative one with a text editor.

**Edit:** Or even better, use eclipse classpath variables in your otherwise absolute pathes, like @taylor-leese commented.

Comment: Instead of relative paths just use Eclipse classpath variables.

Answer (score 16):

For my 2 cents, I would rate it as a bad practice. Projects should not be tied to an IDE, and especially should not be tied to a specific version of an IDE.

Checking in Eclipse config files might work well for simpler and short-term projects. For larger projects that are developed over several years this will generally cause more hassle, as IDE versions change, and project config files don't. Just imagine checking in a 2 year old branch with Eclipse 2.0 config files in Eclipse 4.3 with some customized libraries and m2e integration... No fun at all...

Comment: Imagine a mixed team. Each one adding files from their favorite IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ, NetBeans). I consider it a bad practice.

Answer (score 11):

One thing I would caution against with checking in .classpath file is make sure you don't reference files outside of your project. Eclipse stores the location of these files with a full filepath, and you would need to make sure other developers had those files in exactly the same place.

Comment: Agreed, but this can be avoided by using Eclipse classpath variables. This way the .classpath file can stay the same for each developer and they can just modify the classpath variable for their specific machine.

Answer (score 9):

The key question with all such files is "Can they be reproduced automatically?"  If not, check them into source control.

In this case, I'd say "yes," unless you're using maven, which has m2eclipse and the eclipse plugin to generate them for you.

Comment: i think you meant "In this case, I'd say 'no, they can't be reproduced automatically,'"

Comment: I agree with your meaning. As written you've got two questions.  The implied question: "shall I check them in?" And the explicit question: "can they be reproduced automatically?" And so when you said "yes" you meant the implied question.

Comment: So to clarify : if you're using maven, then you DON'T need to commit these files (.project, .classpath) ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know eclipse preferences files, but with IntelliJ, those files are OS agnostics, which means that it won't ruin your portability. Unless you define libraries with a full path to your system (That would be pretty dangerous/stupid).

When you share preferences, you're sure that everyone will work with the same conditions on the project (plugins configuration, encoding, profiles [for intelliJ]) which can really be a good thing.

It doesn't bother me when some Eclipse files are here, and I think it shouldn't/doesn't really bother other developers when some hidden files just lay there.

Answer (score 3):

We check in .project and .classpath.  With ProjectSet's this allows us to check out complex workspaces with a single "Import Team ProjectSet"

Comment: We have since migrated to maven. Then those files need to be removed from the repository.

Answer (score 2):

> Not checking in .project file will
>   make my development less efficient (I
>   can't simply "import" a project code
>   from a directory)

for this issue, you can choose to create new project and **import existing source**.

one issue with IDE specific files like .project is that other Developers may want to use another IDE do develop the project, so they may add another type of project files. this will make your repo messy.

Comment: ... and this would also include the right jars into the classpath, set the project's compiler compliance level, and load the formatter and compiler warnings configuration?

Comment: Or you have an agreement on which IDE to use and everyone gets the productivity improvement.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to checkin .project and .classpath.

This would be helpful when this project is being **shared by multiple developers.** It becomes **easy and faster to setup development env.** by simply importing this as existing project on any system using eclipse.

Only caution needs to be taken here is classpath's are relative to project.

Comment: or just using classpath variables (e.g. $TOMCAT_HOME)

Answer (score 1):

I often have a similar, more general questionning. The problem essentially is :

- which files am I commiting for *me*?
- which files am I commiting for *others*?
- → How do I combine both objectives of "versionning"?

I offered discussing this [there](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/330770/206473), so you may find more details about the problem, along with interesting solutions :)

---

The one I like best is the use of `git submodule`: keep your `.project` files *etc.* in a private commit repo. And make your final, pure, essential `src` production into a neat `submodule` nugget: a public repo.

```
project/ # root module
|   .git # private repo
|   .project
|   .classpath
|   momsNumber.txt
+---src/     # submodule
|   |   .git # public repo
|   |   main.java
|   +---package/
|   |   |    Etc.java
```

---

[See there anyway.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/330770/206473)

Answer (score 0):

There is not problem of checking in .classpath and .project files into repository. It will help developers which use Eclipse to get going faster.

**Warning**: Make sure your .classpath file is referencing only artifacts which either checked into the repository with the project or can be obtained automatically (such as maven artifacts).