# Grails and .gitigore

Tags: git, grails, version-control

I am just starting out with grails development and was wondering about which files should be ignored within the .gitignore file. Up until now my .gitignore looks like this:

```
*.iws
*Db.properties
*Db.script
.settings
.link_to_grails_plugins
stacktrace.log
/*.zip
/plugin.xml
/*.log
/*DB.*
/cobertura.ser
.DS_Store
/target/
/out/
/web-app/plugins
/web-app/WEB-INF/classes#
```

I am currently using STS from springsource as my IDE. The only to items i cannot figure out are the ".classpath" file and the "target-eclipse" directory. Should I place these two items in the .gitignore file too?

Perhaps someone can help my out with this...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"target-eclipse" and "target"(if you're running from console) should be ignored. It's where the compiled classes sit.

I'd also recommend ignoring '.classpath' since you can generate it using `grails integrate-with --eclipse` but it's a big discussion [whether you should or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611728/java-project-should-classpath-project-file-be-committed-into-repository)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Grails.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Grails.gitignore), part of a collection of lots of gitignore files for various environments.